# Why was my spam flag declined here?

Tags: discussion, spam, flagging

I flagged [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/287314) post as spam because:

- it is plagiarized from [here](https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/using-the-content-type-to-manage-content-consistently) and has a spam link (totally unrelated both to the question and to the answer itself) at the end (typical technique spammers use).
- the username is spammy and the spammer's profile image is related to the URL (both about news)

However, my flag was declined. Why?

Comment: I did not handle that flag, but based on the timeline, I think this was an honest mistake. That was subtle spam; most of what we see is pretty blatant.